# create dataframe that number of rows equals to the sum of values in a column in original dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe like this

```
filmweb   female male   total(female +male)
member     10     5     15
VIP        5      3     8
member     12     nan   12
VIP        7      nan   7
.....
```

Assume there are many different films streaming platforms as the column [filmweb].
If the total number of members is 1000, I want to create a new dataframe that has 1000 rows (as index), and assign 1 if the member is female, 0-male, 1-VIP, 0-not VIP
The final dataframe would be something like

```
     female  male  VIP 
0      1      0     1 
1      0      1     0  
2      1      0     0   
....
999    1      0     1
```

Hopefully, my question makes sense. Thank you ahead.

Comment: Is there a reason why there are some nan values in your first dataframe ? Shouldn't be 0 instead ? If I understand correctly your problem, let's say your first df is all the data you gathered, there are 42 users, so your second dataframe should have 42 rows, am i correct ?

Comment: Hi, in the original dataframe, there are missing values and it is better to leave it like that. And I only count the users from "member" since "VIP" users are part of "member". So for the first 4 rows, it should be converted to 27 rows. That means 15 out of 27 users are VIPs and 12 users are not.

Answer (score -1):

```
def template(f, m, vip):
    return [{'female': f, 'male': m, 'VIP': vip}]

order = ['female', 'male']
totals = df.groupby('filmweb')[order].sum().astype(int)
female, male = totals.loc['member'].sub(totals.loc['VIP'])[order]
vip_female, vip_male = totals.loc['VIP'][order]

new_df = pd.DataFrame(template(1, 0, 0) * female +
                      template(0, 1, 0) * male +
                      template(1, 0, 1) * vip_female +
                      template(0, 1, 1) * vip_male)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
    female  male  VIP
0        1     0    0
1        1     0    0
2        1     0    0
3        1     0    0
4        1     0    0
5        1     0    0
6        1     0    0
7        1     0    0
8        1     0    0
9        1     0    0
10       0     1    0
11       0     1    0
12       1     0    1
13       1     0    1
14       1     0    1
15       1     0    1
16       1     0    1
17       1     0    1
18       1     0    1
19       1     0    1
20       1     0    1
21       1     0    1
22       1     0    1
23       1     0    1
24       0     1    1
25       0     1    1
26       0     1    1
```